# Authentication in laravel

Tags: api, laravel, encryption, authentication

I am making api in laravel. I am using the database that is already built and is live. That system uses md5 with salt values.
I want to do authentication for that system . how should do i have to do?
My source code :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
 $email = $request->input('email');
 $password = md5('testpassword' . 'saltvaluehere');
 try {
        //

        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt([
            'email' => $email,
            'pass' => $password
        ])
        ) {


            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

In core php these authentication is done by:

```
$getpass        = $mydb->CleanString($_POST['password']); 
$getusername    = $mydb->CleanString($_POST['username']);
$dbpass = $mydb->md5_decrypt($mydb->getValue("pass","tbl_admin","username = '".$getusername."'"), SECRETPASSWORD);

    if($dbpass == $getpass){
return 'success full login';
}
```

above code doesnot give same value of hash, so i am not being able to authenticate in system.

Edited:

I have got the password that matched with database but token is not bieng generated.

here is my code:

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request)
{

    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $password = md5($password);



    try {
        //

        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt([
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        ])
        ){

            //return response()->json(compact('token'));
           return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials','_data'=>[$password,$email]], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

can anybody tell me the reason why is token not being generated and why is it saying invalid credintials. as it shows the password and email of database of encrypted form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation I've dealt with and I have foss code to give as a proof of concept.

Essentially, I added another password field for old passwords. I imported users with `password_legacy` set to a JSON object of old password data, in my case:
`{ 'hasher' : 'algo', 'hash' : '#####', 'salt' : 'salt here' }`

Then, I used a modified user service provider so that authentication checked for `password_legacy` if `password` was null. It then used the Illuminate `Hasher` contract as a base and constructed a new instance of a class (dynamically, using the `hasher` property, so for instance a `app\Services\Hashing\AlgoHasher`) and then used that for authentication instead of the default system.

If it did succeed, I `bcrypt`'d the password, set `password` and unset`password_legacy`. This upgraded the password to the much higher standard of security that bcrypt offered.

Migration code for new field:
https://github.com/infinity-next/infinity-next/blob/ccb01c753bd5cedd75e03ffe562f389d690de585/database/migrations_0_3_0/2015_06_12_181054_password_legacy.php

Modified user provider:
https://github.com/infinity-next/infinity-next/blob/ccb01c753bd5cedd75e03ffe562f389d690de585/app/Providers/EloquentUserProvider.php

Hasher contract for Vichan (md5+salt):
https://github.com/infinity-next/infinity-next/blob/ccb01c753bd5cedd75e03ffe562f389d690de585/app/Services/Hashing/VichanHasher.php

Relevant user code:
https://github.com/infinity-next/infinity-next/blob/ccb01c753bd5cedd75e03ffe562f389d690de585/app/User.php#L124-L165

Hope that helps!